# Need to Write Data from CAPL to C# code and read back to CAPL script

Tags: c#, capl

I am using CANoe tool for CAPL scripting.

And I have referred this link for help given by Vector: https://vector.com/portal/medien/cmc/application_notes/AN-IND-1-011_Using_CANoe_NET_API.pdf

Now I am facing issue at step or section: 2.7 Calling CAPL Functions.
There are no syntax errors, but I think, the code is not able to retrieve the function from the CAPL file as it is giving this error when I pass values to the function from C# code.

**Error statement:**

> An exception of type
>   'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in
>   System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Cannot convert null to 'int' because it is a
>   non-nullable value type
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

**Can some one tell me what exactly the issue is?**

Code:

```
public void Init()
{
 CANoe.Application myApp;
 myApp = new CANoe.Application();
 CANoe.Measurement mymeasure;
 mymeasure = (CANoe.Measurement)myApp.Measurement;
 myApp.Open(@"D:\Planter CAPl\CANoeCAPLdll.cfg", true, true);
 CANoe.OpenConfigurationResult ocresult = myApp.Configuration.OpenConfigurationResult;

 if (ocresult.result == 0)
   {
     CANoe.CAPL CANoeCAPL = (CANoe.CAPL)myApp.CAPL;
     CANoeCAPL.Compile(null);
     CANoe.CAPLFunction mydata;
     mydata = (CANoe.CAPLFunction)CANoeCAPL.GetFunction("Data");//CANoeCAPL.GetFunction("DataShare");

      mymeasure.Start();
      Thread.Sleep(2000);
      int Result = (int)mydata.Call(10,20,30);// Exeception error is coming at this point*

       if (mymeasure.Running)
         {
           mymeasure.Stop();
         }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error message is relatively self-explanatory, you're trying to convert a `null` value to an `int` type. Since `int` is a value type, it cannot be `null`, therefore, you get an exception.

In the line

```
int Result = (int)mydata.Call(10,20,30);
```

The value returned by `mydata.Call(10,20,30)` is `null`. You should check if that value is null and do something.

```
var myDataResult = mydata.Call(10,20,30);
if(myDataResult == null)
   // do something
else
   int result = (int)myDataResult;
```

As to why the call to the `Call` method returns `null`, you'll have to check the API you're using.